# error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: c++

I was wondering whether you guys could help me with a few errors I've commented out below. Can't believe I have this many already.

```
class CalculusWizard
{

    private: 
        const static char varChars[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }; // error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before '{' token, error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-itegral type 'const char[]'
        const static size_t varCharsLen = sizeof(varChars) / sizeof(const char); 
        const static enum functop = {NONE, PLUS, MINUS, TIMES, DIVIDE, COMPOSITION}; // error: use of enum 'functop' without previous declaration, error: unexpected qualified-id before '=' token
        bool isVariable(const char &);

    public: 
        CalculusWizard();
        ~CalculusWizard();
        std::string derivative(std::string &, const char &, unsigned &);

};

bool CalculusWizard::isVariable(const char & c)
{
    char * thisptr = varChars; // error: 'varChars' was not declared in this scope
    char * offend = varChars + varCharsLen;
    while (thisptr != offend)
        if (*thisptr++ == c)
            return true;
    return false;
    /*
     Alternatively, return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'
}
```

Also, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do with `varChars` ???? The point is, I need an array of characters that every instance of `CalculusWizard` refers to. I thought a private `static` member was the way to go.

Comment: Either upgrade your compiler to one with C++11 support, or put the definition outside the class.

Comment: The enum syntax appears to be simply incorrect.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ideone.com's C++11 complains about trying to initialise the static member `varChars` from a brace-enclosed list; meanwhile, moving its definition below the class causes it to complain that `sizeof` is being called on an incomplete type (https://ideone.com/LwKEGD).  Not sure there's any way to get the size of that array into a *compile-time* constant.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Don't see your problem.  Of course the usage of `sizeof` goes after the definition that determines the size.  https://ideone.com/0rCpdd

Comment: @BenVoigt: The only limitation seems to be that anything that must be declared *inside the class declaration* can't use `varCharsLen` as a compile-time constant -- e.g. `doesntWork[]` in http://ideone.com/6odOfv.  But indeed it seems to usable in this way after its definition (e.g. for `willWork[]` and `thisWorks[]`).

Comment: As a design point, since these members are `private` and `const`, there's not really any need to have them as part of the class definition; if all of your function implementations are in one unit you could just add those things as globals in that unit (within an anonymous namespace).  The fewer implementation details that you need to expose to users of your class, the better.